# How to update a checkbox/radio button with rails3-jquery-autocomplete

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete

I am using rails3-jquery-autocomplete gem to fetch the autocomplete items from the database along with some extra data that I need to pre-fill a form.

`autocomplete :link, :name, :extra_data => [:url, :is_full_screen, :is_auto_trigger, :is_ad, :is_ecommerce]`

Everything other than the url are boolean flags (user preferences) that are used to check/uncheck checkboxes and select radio buttons in a form. Even though the gem updates a text field, but it does not automatically update checkboxes and radio buttons. I have already specified :update_elements in form view:

`<%= f.autocomplete_field :name, autocomplete_link_path, :update_elements => {:url => '#link_url', :is_auto_trigger => '#link_is_auto_trigger'}`

How do I do this? I tried exploring the railsAutocomplete.select javascript event that gets fired when the option is selected, to execute custom js to select checkboxes and radio buttons, but how do I get the data (from sql query) in that event listener? Is their a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm wondering how to get it to select a value from a drop-down based on some `extra_data`.

Comment: Er, never mind, auto-selecting from the drop-down worked after I corrected a typo. I can see how checkboxes and radio buttons would be a bigger challenge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by executing custom javascript to update checkbox/radio on selecting one of the autocomplete options. A javascript event named `railsAutocomplete.select` is fired on the input field when a value is selected from the autocomplete drop down. The data.item has all the data that you fetched from the databases (including the extra data):

```
    $('#link_name').bind('railsAutocomplete.select', function(event, data){
      // Custom JS to select radio/checkbox, or do any other complex task
      select_linktype(data.item.linktype);
      select_tracking(data.item.is_ad);
    });
```